# How to disable user from liking a post after reloading app?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

In my `viewController`, which is a `PFQueryTableViewController`,I am trying to create a like button feature for my posts within a TableViewCell that is enabled initially, but after the user likes the post we have a PFRelation(userLike) for that in Parse. When a user likes a post on the app, after reloading the app again, the user can like it again. I don't want the user to like it again. When reloading the app, I would like to have the like button disable itself after its pressed, while checking Parse for that Relation of the current user to see if they have liked the post already. Is there something I need to do in my code to disable the user from liking the same post again? I've pasted my code below to get a better idea

The commented statements are what I have tried to use in order to implement that feature.

```
    @IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {

        //let object: PFObject = self.objects?[sender.tag] as! PFObject

        let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

        if sender.enabled == true{


            disableButton(sender)


            object!.incrementKey("count", byAmount: 1)

            self.userLike?.addObject(object!)
            globalLikeList.append(object!)


        } else {


            enableButton(sender)


            object!.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)

            self.userLike?.removeObject(object!)

            if let index = globalLikeList.indexOf(object!) {
                globalLikeList.removeAtIndex(index)
            }

        }

//        let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
//        let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
//        let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
//        self.userLike?.addObject(object)
//        tweet.addObject(object)

        object!.saveInBackground()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
        NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
    }
```

We also initialized a global array of likes to store those "like" objects

```
var globalLikeList: [PFObject] = []
```

And also here is what we did in our tableView. Here is where I believe I've configured the like button:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
   let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tweetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! tweet

    if let tweet : PFObject = self.tweets.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {


    if let likeScore = object[("count")] as? Int {
            cell.likeCount.text = "\(likeScore)"
        }

        if globalLikeList.contains(object!) {

            cell.likeButton.selected = true

        } else {
            cell.likeButton.selected = false
        }
        cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath!.row


        }

        }



    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you check to see if you've liked the post already, you have `cell.likeButton.selected = true`. I think you want `cell.likeButton.enabled = false`

Comment: That didn't work. I'm still able to like the users post again.